# TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

my problem is, when i want to scroll to a specified li **(#vor)** it always shows me this errror.

Cannot read property 'top' of undefined jquery animation

```
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($("#vor").offset().top-$('#header').outerHeight(true))+'px'},
'slow');
```

Comment: Try writting this script after </body> as you will refer to DOM after it's loaded.

Comment: Does `#vor` definitely exist?

Comment: Is this inside the document ready handler?

Comment: @billyonecan yes it realy exists

Comment: @Barmar it is inside of the ready handler

Comment: Can you post the markup for your `#vor` element?

Comment: Put `console.log($("#vor").offset())` before this.

Comment: @billyonecan  <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" id="#vor">${head_name}</li>

Comment: Remove the `#` from `vor` -> `id="vor"`

Comment: @Barmar       Object {top: 1200.25, left: 0}

Comment: @billyonecan always the same error..

Comment: Can you show the entire function that contains this? There must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Barmar   http://jsfiddle.net/2aXHy/1/

pls help me im to confused now...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var offset = $("#vor").offset();
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: (offset.top - $('#header').outerHeight(true))+'px'},
'slow');
```

Comment: Why should that make a difference? All you're doing is putting the expression into a variable. If it was undefined before, it will still be undefined.

Comment: @Barmar .offset() returns an object containing the properties top and left. Refer this http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: I understand that. His original code accesses the `top` property of what `.offset()` returns just like yours does.

Comment: Yes I also explained the same thing in my answer, I don't thing its wrong, to downvote it.

Comment: @ChiragVidani: Basically he is trying to tell you that there isn't much difference with what he has done and what you suggested.